# Cannot mutate collection across threads - Rust

Tags: rust

I'm practicing rust and trying to create a simple grep program, when trying to iterate over the paths and subpaths in a current directory the programs exists after the first path (the user input), where as it should find matches in nested subfolders.

After a debugging the program I noticed that `queue1` isn't being mutated. the contents do not change (if they were it would have worked).

I have tried the same program without inserting to `queue1` (just removing values, without making a copy with a mutex) and it worked fine.

I can't understand why `queue1` isn't being mutated, I have wrapped it with an `Arc` and a `Mutex`. The program should push to the de-queue inside the threads and iterate over it with the loop, but after pushing the original queue is left empty and the program exists, while the "other" (perhaps these queues are copies that exists somewhere else?) queue (queue3) do contain the items whilst in the closure.

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::{fs};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use threadpool::ThreadPool;

#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    pattern: String,

    #[clap(parse(from_os_str))]
    path: PathBuf,
}

fn main() {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(4);
    let queue1: Arc<Mutex<VecDeque<PathBuf>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()));

    match Cli::parse() {
        Cli { path, pattern } => {
            let pattern_ref = Arc::new(pattern.clone());

            queue1.lock().unwrap().push_back(path);

            while !queue1.lock().unwrap().is_empty() {
                let pattern_ref = pattern_ref.clone();
                let queue2 = queue1.clone();

                let path = queue1.lock().unwrap().pop_front().unwrap();

                pool.execute(move || {
                    if path.is_dir() {
                        let mut queue3 = queue2.lock().unwrap();

                        path.read_dir().unwrap()
                            .map(|r| r.unwrap())
                            .for_each(|p| queue3.push_back(p.path()));

                        return;
                    }

                    // else do something
                });
            }
        }
    }

    pool.join();
}
```

Comment: Looks like what you want is a channel.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I had that thought, but I don't understand why I need a channel. I'm passing the queue as a reference to all other threads.

Comment: I'm not saying it cannot work this way, but channels are more efficient for message passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a race between the outer loop which empties the queue and the threads inside the pool which try to fill it.

So what happens on the first iteration is:

- you put an item in the queue
- the queue is not empty
- the item is removed from the queue
- the work is sent to the threadpool
- go around the loop
- the queue is empty
- exit

Meanwhile the threadpool has to stat() the path to check if it's a dir, then read its contents, then iterate on that.

Going around the loop is instantaneous, while performing multiple filesystem calls very much is not. You need some sort of wait group, through which the worker threads can signal that they're done with the work, and the main loop can wait on *that* signal.

Furthermore, even if it did work your locking is set up such that there's basically no possible concurrency: the longest part of the work by far is reading the contents of the directory, but the queue is locked for the entire iteration, in your snippet the only thing that's done in parallel is checking that the path is a directory (well and popping from the queue to push a job in the threadpool I guess).

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the issue, can't believe I missed this...